# Does jquery .width(value) resize the images within a container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question is simple, and hope the answer is as well:

I have a div (call it div A) which is dynamically resized according to the viewport dimensions. The div contains a couple of images (which are around 3000px * 3000px) which I am loading in two divs (call it div B and div C) below each other inside Div A. Div B and Div C are set to 200px x 200px and the images are set to 100% of Div B and Div C.

I want to know if the following code will also resize the images in children div B and div C.

```
$('#divA').width(foo)
```

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: works. But hogs memory when i render my web pages inside a iOS web view and my app crashes. The moment i comment out the $('#divA').width(foo) line, the app stabilizes. So want to know why the width(foo) is memory heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Size of images will only change when you modify the height and width of immediate parent. If DivB and DivC are also height 50% and width 100% of DivA, then $('DivA').width(foo) will change the image dimensions.

Comment: What do you mean by change in the image dimension? Will a image resize be done by jquery? Something is happening in the width(foo) function of jquery that is hogging too much memory when I call it. My gut feeling says that its taking a copy of my image in the memory and resizing it. I dont know. Any clue?